# JPQL avg function for TimeStamp

Tags: hibernate, date, timestamp, average, jpql

I need a JPQL query which should count average days between two dates. 
I wrote the query like this

```
select avg(ps.begins-ps.ends) from PackStatus ps where ps.status.code = 'serviceExec'
            and ps.gossrvcDocPackage.serviceId = 'Usl_3641042_RSOC'
            and ps.begins between :startDate and :endDate
            and ps.ends between :startDate and :endDate
```

But the system throws exception "org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query"
If I put some other field, e.g avg(ps.id) it works fine.
In database ps.ends and ps.begins are stored as timestapm.
How can I count avg days between two dates?
Thanks.

Comment: Is avg(day(ps.ends)-day(ps.begins)) the right way for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to find avg difference between dates in days is

```
select avg(day(ps.ends)-day(ps.begins)) from PackStatus ps where ps.status.code = 'serviceExec'
        and ps.gossrvcDocPackage.serviceId = 'Usl_3641042_RSOC'
        and ps.begins between :startDate and :endDate
        and ps.ends between :startDate and :endDate
```

Also you can find difference in hours,minutes, etc. Just replace day() on hour() or other measure.